TensorFlow Liteの初期化時にアクセス異常になってしまう
Spresense SDK環境でTensorFlow Liteを搭載しようとしていますが、ランタイムの初期化 tflm_runtime_initialize でアクセス異常となってしまいます。
サンプルプログラム tflmrt_lenet で問題なく動作することを確認できたため、サンプルプログラムから移植した初期化のみのコードを作成しましたが、エラーとなります。
エラーとなるmainソースをexampls/tflmrt_lenet/tflmrt_lenet_main.cへ移植しても問題なく動作するため、もしわかる方がいれば教えて頂きたいです。(defineなどの宣言もサンプルから移植しています)
ファイル構成
my_app_main.c: 作成しているメインソース
loader_tflite.c: サンプルプログラム tflmrt_lenet からコピー
loader_tflite.h: サンプルプログラム tflmrt_lenet からコピー
model.c: サンプルプログラム tflmrt_lenet からコピー (TFLモデル本体)
mainソース (サンプルプログラム tflmrt_lenet の main() の初期化部分以外をコメントアウト)
main()
{
 int ret = 0;
  int i;
  float proc_time;
  float norm_factor;
//   const void *inputs[1] = { s_img_buffer };
  tflm_runtime_t rt;
  tflm_config_t config = { .cpu_num = 1 };
  void *network;
//   my_setting_t setting = { 0 };
  struct timeval begin;
  struct timeval end;


//   parse_args(argc, argv, &setting);

//   /* load an hand-written digit image into s_img_buffer,
//    * and then divide the pixels by 255.0 for normalization
//    */

//   norm_factor = setting.skip_norm ? 1.0f : 255.0f;
//   if (setting.pgm_path)
//     {
//       ret = pnm_load(setting.pgm_path, norm_factor,
//                     s_img_buffer, sizeof(s_img_buffer));
//       if (ret)
//         {
//           printf("load pgm image failed due to %d\n", ret);
//           goto pgm_error;
//         }
//     }
//   else
//     {
//       for (i = 0; i < MNIST_SIZE_PX; i++)
//         {
//           s_img_buffer[i] = image0[i] / norm_factor;
//         }
//     }

//   /* load a model file, which holds a network structure and weight values,
//    * into a heap memory
//    */

//   if (setting.model_path)
//     {
//       network = alloc_tflite_network(setting.model_path);
//       if (network == NULL)
//         {
//           printf("load model file failed\n");
//           goto pgm_error;
//         }
//     }
//   else
//     {
//       network = (void *) model_tflite;
//     }
      network = (void *) model_tflite;

  /* initialize the whole tflmrt subsystem */

  ret = tflm_initialize(&config);
  if (ret)
    {
      printf("tflm_initialize() failed due to %d", ret);
      return;
    }

  /* instantiate a neural network in a tflm_runtime_t object */

  ret = tflm_runtime_initialize(&rt, network, TFLM_TENSOR_ARENA_SIZE);
  if (ret)
    {
      printf("tflm_runtime_initialize() failed due to %d\n", ret);
      goto rt_error;
    }

  printf("ARENA Size: %d\n", tflm_runtime_actual_arenasize(&rt));

  /* convert the image data to datatype this tflm_runtime_t expects */

//   ret = convert_datatype(&rt);
//   if (ret)
//     {
//       printf("convert_datatype() failed due to %d\n", ret);
//       goto rt_error;
//     }

  /* perform inference after feeding inputs */

  printf("start tflm_runtime_forward()\n");
//   gettimeofday(&begin, 0);
//   ret = tflm_runtime_forward(&rt, inputs, 1);
//   gettimeofday(&end, 0);
  if (ret)
    {
      printf("tflm_runtime_forward() failed due to %d\n", ret);
      goto fin;
    }

  /* show the classification result and its processing time */

//   for (i = 0; i < tflm_runtime_output_shape(&rt, 0, 1); i++)
//     {
//       printf("output[%u]=%.6f\n", i, get_output(&rt, i));
//     }

//   proc_time = (float)end.tv_sec + (float)end.tv_usec / 1.0e6;
//   proc_time -= (float)begin.tv_sec + (float)begin.tv_usec / 1.0e6;
  printf("inference time=%.3f\n", proc_time);

fin:

  /* free memories allocated to tflm_runtime_t */

  tflm_runtime_finalize(&rt);
rt_error:

  /* finalize the whole tflmrt subsystem */

  tflm_finalize();

pgm_error:
  return ;
}

エラー発生時の表示
arm_hardfault: Hard Fault escalation:
arm_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard Fault!:
arm_hardfault:  IRQ: 3 regs: 0x2d0a5780
arm_hardfault:  BASEPRI: 000000e0 PRIMASK: 00000000 IPSR: 00000003 CONTROL: 00000000
arm_hardfault:  CFSR: 00008200 HFSR: 40000000 DFSR: 00000000 BFAR: 0443f9b9 AFSR: 00000000
arm_hardfault: Hard Fault Reason:
_assert: Current Version: NuttX  12.3.0 SDK3.2.0-186214b-dirty Oct  4 2024 11:52:20 arm
_assert: Assertion failed panic: at file: :0 task:  0
up_dump_register: R0: 2d0a5864 R1: 0443f99d R2: 2d0a58a4  R3: 0d06bf8d
up_dump_register: R4: 0443f99d R5: 0d075a15 R6: 00000000  FP: 00000000
up_dump_register: R8: 00000000 SB: 00000000 SL: 00000000 R11: 00000000
up_dump_register: IP: 00000014 SP: 2d0a5858 LR: 0d06b917  PC: 0d06bfe8
up_dump_register: xPSR: 01000000 BASEPRI: 000000e0 CONTROL: 00000000
up_dump_register: EXC_RETURN: ffffffed
dump_stacks: ERROR: Stack pointer is not within the stack
dump_stack: IRQ Stack:
dump_stack:   base: 0x2d0944c8
dump_stack:   size: 00002048
stack_dump: 0x2d094a60: deadbeef deadbeef deadbeef deadbeef 0000000a 2d094adb 00000002 00000000
stack_dump: 0x2d094a80: 00000080 2d094b14 0000000a 0d015bf9 0d015be7 2d094b14 0000005f 0d00ce5b

環境
Windows 11
WSL2環境
Spresense VSCode IDE：1.5.100
spresense-sdk：v3.2.0

dump_stacks: ERROR: Stack pointer is not within the stack というログから
スタックオーバーフロー (このサイトのことではなく :-) が発生している可能性は無いでしょうか？
exampls/tflmrt_lenetサンプルのスタックサイズは 8192 になっているようです。
examples/tflmrt_lenet/Kconfig
config EXAMPLES_TFLMRT_LENET_STACKSIZE
    int "tflmrt_lenet stack size"
    default 8192

オリジナルで作成しているアプリケーションのスタックサイズを増やしてみるとどうなるでしょうか。
(既に試していたり見当違いであればすみません)

ありがとうございます。まさにその通りでした。初歩的な部分ですみませんでした。大変助かりました。
